# Could not find the sitemap node with URL '/login' in sitefinity

Tags: sitefinity, sitefinity-10, sitefinity-5, sitefinity-8, sitefinity-feather

Iam trying to creating a multi-language site. After enabling the 2nd language, I tried to load the page using the pages section in sitefinity, at that time this error is triggering. Can you please help me to overcome this.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9LOA0.png)

Comment: which page are you trying to load - can you provide the url ?

Comment: It's a home page and it's in my local.http://localhost:21019/startseite/Action/Edit/de

Comment: and what about this /login page - do you have it?

Comment: When I'm previewing it from the administrator I'm getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a permission-related issue. Check this KB article and see if the resolution/workaround sections would help: https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/could-not-find-the-sitemap-node-with-url

**Resolution**:

> Change permissions for all pages to add the "Authenticated" Role Then
> assign permissions to each individual page separately where needed.
> For example, for pages which should be accessed only by Authors or
> Editors

**Workaround**:

> Change the permissions for all users to have the Editor role.